# How to include column and rows ranges within the same line of code?

Tags: excel, vba

On this occasion I am working on a code to copy a range of data, tailor it into HTML, and then paste it in a new email which will later be sent.

My issue is, I need the range to always be A1:M1 plus End(xlDown). My code does not seem to support these two variables, as it everytime leads me to the error message.

I have tried to look into forums on how I can parametrize these two in a single line (for I think it is the way my code requires this to be done) without luck.

Below is my code:

```
Sub email()  
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set Rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
 
    Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:M1").End(xlDown).Select.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    ' SET Outlook APPLICATION OBJECT.
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' CREATE EMAIL OBJECT.
    Dim objEmail As Object
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With objEmail
        .SendUsingAccount = "ccaprimarysupply@diageo.com"
        .To = "jorgeluis.martineznieto@diageo.com ; ccaprimarysupply@diageo.com"
        .CC = "sara.garamvolgyi@diageo.com ; david.kovacs@diageo.com"
        .Subject = "Daily Invoices"
        .Bodyformat = 2
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(Rng)
        .Importance = 2
        .Display        ' DISPLAY MESSAGE.
    End With
    
    ' CLEAR.
    Set objEmail = Nothing:    Set objOutlook = Nothing
        
ErrHandler:
    '
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(Rng As Range)
    ' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    Rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Note: The code was taken from https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail3.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? `Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1:M" & Range("A1:M1").End(xlDown).Row)`

Comment: Note, you should always tell which error message you get and in which line if you ask a question.

Comment: Also, what is the Select() call doing? Select() does not return a range object, so you cant call SpecialCells() on it.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your messages.

Horst, indeed it solved my issue. Thank you very much.
PeH, thanks. I will do it the next time. Still trying to get used to this forum.
DS_London, honestly I am not certain. There are several lines I do not understand from the codes sometimes. Still learning.

Once again, thanks to all.